# What is the Filter equivalent of TermQuery?

Tags: lucene

I'm doing some complex querying using Lucene 4.0, and my information-retrieval-theory buddy has told me that anywhere that I can use a filter instead of a query, I should, in order to improve performance. Therefore, I decided to take one particularly hairy component of the query and transform it into a filter. This is relatively straightforward, as there are `Filter` equivalents of `BooleanQuery` and `NumericRangeQuery`, but there doesn't seem to be a `TermFilter` equivalent of `TermQuery`. There is a `FieldValueFilter`, but that seems only to filter on the presence of a given field, not a particular value in that field.

What filter should I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [TermsFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/TermsFilter.html) is what you are looking for.